# Codename One URLImage reduce image resolution and size

Tags: codenameone

The app I am building is to take a member picture and save to amazon s3 bucket. 
Again thanks Codename one team( especially Shai) for helping me out through the process.

I am now facing some performance issue as in I am using iPhone 6s Plus.  When I take the picture and reload the label with the image, it takes really long time to load.

Is there any way to reduce the picture size and resolution before saving to amazon s3 bucket?  Or what would be the best practice or optimized way of achieving this?  Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use the [version of capture that accepts width/height](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/capture/Capture.html#capturePhoto-int-int-) notice that -1 will keep the aspect ratio for that axis.

You can also use [ImageIO](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/util/ImageIO.html) to resize an image to any arbitrary size without opening the file.

Comment: Thank you Shai, 
I'll try that solution and will update the question.